# ng-bootstrap and Angular 5 compatibility

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Was ng-bootstrap already tested with Angular 5 and is it compatible ?

If not, any compatible ng-bootsrap angular 5 release planned ?

Thanks !

Comment: Nothing to worry about , angular 5 doen't made any breaking changes coding part, so you are good to go.

Comment: @VivekDoshi I'm getting UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY errors trying to use both ng-bootstrap and angular 5

Answer (score 7):

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pull/1939) to add angular 5 support for ng-bootstrap.

I hope it will be released soon.

**UPDATE:**

It's now released: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta7-2017-12-08

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ng-bootstrap is supported with Angular 5 yet, this is what I got creating a new app

```
Tzachs-MBP:src tzachs$ npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
ng4fbbootstrap@0.0.0 /Users/tzachs/personal/login/ng4fbbootstrap
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.0.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.0.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@5.0.2
`-- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5

npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.0.3 but none was installed.
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**: I was not aware that there was a difference between ng-bootstrap and @ng-bootstrap on NPMjs. Of course [@ng-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) is what you are talking about, and this is currently dependent on Angular 4.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

ng-bootstrap is dependent on Angular 4.

I suggest moving to ngx-bootstrap (ng-bootstrap name change to 'x') that will support all future versions of Angular.

My reference is from the NPMjs page for [ng-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-bootstrap) writing that ng-bootstrap package changed name to ngx-bootstrap.